# Let's get critical: Apr 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Pets Stack Exchange](http://pets.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://pets.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Is it okay to feed my cats canned tuna?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2590/is-it-okay-to-feed-my-cats-canned-tuna)

**Net Score: 9** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Why does my dog get scared when approached and petted?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2425/why-does-my-dog-get-scared-when-approached-and-petted)

**Net Score: 9** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Can rabbits drink from a bowl of water?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2354/can-rabbits-drink-from-a-bowl-of-water)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [I train 2-on/2-off contacts, what exercises I can use to help keep them consistent?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2409/i-train-2-on-2-off-contacts-what-exercises-i-can-use-to-help-keep-them-consiste)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Is overhead cable running leash suitable for all dogs?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2527/is-overhead-cable-running-leash-suitable-for-all-dogs)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [In dog agility, what is a stopped contact and what is a running contact?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2453/in-dog-agility-what-is-a-stopped-contact-and-what-is-a-running-contact)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 12, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How can I get my cat to clean himself?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2395/how-can-i-get-my-cat-to-clean-himself)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Teaching a dog to play fetch](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2461/teaching-a-dog-to-play-fetch)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [What are the effects of ticks on dogs and does it transmit diseases?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2554/what-are-the-effects-of-ticks-on-dogs-and-does-it-transmit-diseases)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 11, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [What are "growth plates" in dogs?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2455/what-are-growth-plates-in-dogs)

**Net Score: -5** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 7)

---

Answer (score 4):

I noticed that as far as search results go. I either saw them in the top 5 results, or I couldn't find them at all, even when looking through the first 3 pages. Sometimes even using the title of the question in the search.

Comment: Yes, I saw this too. I also tried more generic terms and such. We're a little hit and miss.

Comment: Which, by the way, I think is because they're really no more informative than other sources or, in the odd case, less so.

Comment: Actually I thought the ones where we were the only real source were easy to find. What effects do ticks have on dogs, and how do I get my cat to clean itself, were the two I had trouble finding.

Comment: I had trouble with several. I was about 50/50 on that front, to be honest. I also suspect I might be a little more critical than some.